# Makefile will not do a final copy of target file

Tags: makefile

I have an interesting problem. I have a makefile that builds files, then post processes them, then copies the final processed file to a release folder.

When I run `make`, it will build everything correctly and then finishes without copying the final target file to the release folder. I have to run make again for it to see that the generated (newly built) file is newer than the release target and will copy it over.

I have even put in a `sleep 5` to delay the final release target check to allow any file IO to finish and update the newly built file with the proper timestamp.

```
release : ./release/file.xml

./release/file.xml : gen/file_processed.xml sleep
    cp gen/file_processed.xml ./release/file.xml

gen/file_processed.xml : gen/file.xml
    python2.6 post_processing_scripts.py #saves output as gen/file_processed.xml

gen/file.xml : source_files
    command to compile gen/file.xml

sleep :
    sleep 5
```

What isn't working is make thinks that after it compiles all the other targets and executes the sleep recipe to wait 5 seconds, it still says that `gen/file_processed.xml` is older than the release target. I have to rerun make to get that final step completed.

Any ideas as to what I can add to let the generated file finish updating before it checks it against the release target?

Thanks so much for your help, I appreciate it!

Cheers,

Brad

UPDATE:

I changed the code so that the question about the sleep command executing always is removed. it still behaves the same as described above however.

```
release : ./release/file.xml

./release/file.xml : gen/file_processed.xml
    cp gen/file_processed.xml ./release/file.xml

gen/file_processed.xml : gen/file.xml
    python2.6 post_processing_scripts.py #saves output as gen/file_processed.xml; sleep 5;

gen/file.xml : source_files
    command to compile gen/file.xml
```

I still need to run make twice to get it to copy the final file over.

I will try and make sure this example exactly maps what my original makefile is doing.

Comment: So... which rule are you running?

Comment: The existence of the sleep rule means that it will ALWAYS copy the file to the release directory every time you run make, regardless of whether any of the source files have changed (unless you happen to have a file or directory called 'sleep').  Remove the sleep dependency and it will copy only when source_files changes.

Comment: The only way I can see you getting the behavior you describe is if your python script forks and continues running in the background after the shell that invoked it exits...

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams this occurs when I run release.

Comment: @ChrisDodd correct...it always executes sleep, but that's not a big deal at this point to me. As for the python code...there is no parallel programming going on...its just plain python (no threads or forking or anything like that).

Comment: Try replacing the `python2.6 ...` rule with `touch $@`. Does the problem persist?

Comment: So that led me to notice one key difference in the example script above and what I am actually doing...my rules are based on the log file outputs of these commands, not the actual compiled files. I changed the rules over to reference the actual files I cared about instead of the log files and it works perfectly now. Funny though, that it had worked for the past 6 months all the way up until I added the final copy at the end. @Beta, thanks for that test...it told me that `logs/post_processing_scripts.txt` was the output the make file cared about...not the actual xml it was compiling.

Comment: So how does this work...can I close this question or does a moderator or someone with more reputation have to do it? The "problem" I've outlined above isn't a problem, as @ChrisDodd accurately pointed out.

Comment: I flagged as an incomplete question, so hopefully that gets it taken care of. Sorry for wasting your time, I appreciate your help!